# Batch convert 5000 vectors to PNG with transparency

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, inkscape, svg

I have 5000 vector images (mostly eps / svg) that i need to convert to PNG with transparent backgrounds. PNG images need to be maximum 4000x4000px

Any idea what would be the best way to do this ? Most batch image converters won't support transparency and resizing.

The first part of the task (vector to PNG) could be done using illustrator or photoshop actions, but i haven't found a way to set max size at 4000x4000 while keeping aspect ratio and maximum resolution matching the requirements

One option could be to split the task and run the PNG through something else to resize them to maximum 4000x4000px... Maybe Inkscape ? I saw some people were able to write python scripts to do similar tasks

the problem is that it's hard to set the 4000x4000px limit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be a job for the command line tool [Image Magick *mogrify*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php). The following command:

```
mogrify -resize '4000x4000' -format png *.svg
```

Will convert all SVG files in the current folder to PNG keeping the aspect ratio but with the largest side exactly 4000 pixels.

In case we had defined a non-transparent white (or any other [color](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fill)) background in the source SVG we can add transparency with:

```
mogrify -resize '4000x4000' -transparent white -format png *.svg
```

---

**Note on Windows command line:**
We need to prefix the commands with `magick` and should not use ticks `'` but nothing, or quote marks `"` instead.

An example Windows command may look like this:

```
magick mogrify -resize "4000x4000" -transparent white -format png *.svg
```

---

Converting [EPS files need a density value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583821/how-to-convert-a-eps-file-to-a-high-quality-1024x1024-jpg) (in DPI) in addition:

```
magick mogrify -resize "4000x4000" -density 300 -transparent white -format png *.eps
```

Comment: I'm totally noob could you link to some documentation about the usage of ImageMagick with windows ? i did read the docs on the official website, i did exactlty what they suggested, installed ImageMagick for Windows and tried to run your commands through a CMD prompt or WindowsPowershell but it always say "the command mogrify is not recognized".... What am i missing ?

Comment: Convert command seems recognized but i get an error about the parameter 4000x4000 https://gyazo.com/e9a8e86909ae9514ba7ffa152aff4b87 .... The install path of ImageMagick is default Programs folder, but searching for "morgrify" inside that folder doesn't return any executable file https://gyazo.com/45572dbacc8ecae2b990063f40f92757 .... I just installed default ImageMagick for windows, did i need anything else ? Thanks!

Comment: It's working !!!! Thank you so much ! You just saved me DAYS of work !

Comment: When testing this command with EPS instead of *.svg i get a weird error : https://gyazo.com/7d4ecc904702e94f0d813588f7bdd45c

Comment: The output result of the EPS file looks like this : https://gyazo.com/0d2d313b73d669ef0c92eca9855c23e5
If i open the same image in illustrator and convert it to SVG instead, save it in the exact same folder, then run the script with *.svg parameter the output PNG looks good and there is no error... So it doesn't look like a path error, or an error with the graphic file... SVG are converted correctly, but not EPS :(

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! Tested the command, i get a different error but same result (pixelised png) https://gyazo.com/a59aa279458bcc5e9a584212368d7373

Comment: Apparently "PNG does not support dpi, only dots per centimeter. So Imagemagick is (supposed to) convert your 300 dpi to the equivalent dpc automatically"
I also tested with different parameters without success : -units PixelsPerCentimeters -colorspace sRGB -density 300

Comment: For image sharpness we need to adapt the density values to match our needs... the more the sharper the resulting PNG. For 4000x4000 px size try with density 1200 or more (but note that the higher the density the more resources we need for calculating the result).

Comment: Even with 1200 density, here's how it looks compared to original : https://gyazo.com/edc9174796ea8c3130e9fc8e17933528
Resources is not a problem, i have i7 4.4ghz 6950x (10-core) + 64gb ddr4 + GTX 1080 Titan X + 1tb SSD 960 Pro

Comment: Looks like a dithering artifact. Could this be a bitmap embedded in an EPS?

Comment: i shared my source EPS and more details here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&p=140862#p140862

Comment: Here's my try of a 4000px hight image with density 4800: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Elc.png (cropped because of size) - looks ok to me.